# Doctrine Abstract - Concrete class ORM

Tags: orm, doctrine, abstract-class, symfony

I'm working with doctrine for the mapping of some objects to database tables.
This is what I have now:

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="account")
 */
abstract class Account{
   /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="string")
   */
   private $username;

   /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="string")
   */
   private $password;

   /*Getters and setters*/
}

 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="player")
 */
abstract class Player extends Account{

   /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   */
   private $number;

   /*Getters and setters*/
}


 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="coach")
 */
abstract class Coach extends Account{

   /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   */
   private $experience;

   /*Getters and setters*/
}
```

This way, all concrete classes will have the username and the password column, what if I would need to store only the username in order to be able to join them later and get the oconcrete object back? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having trouble understanding your requirements but perhaps mapped super classes will help: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: The reason why I nedd to save both the Account Class and the subclasses is because later I will need to let them exchange some messages and I have tought to make a message entity with sender and receiver fields wich are 2 foreign keys to the username in the account table.

Comment: All I can say is that you seem to be overly focused on the database design i.e. repeated mentions of foreign keys and tables.  Doctrine is an ORM intended to abstract away the actual persistence process.  Design your entities to fit your use case then worry about the database mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is then possibly Class Table Inheritance as described in http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

```
namespace MyProject\Model;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"player" = "Player", "coach" = "Coach"})
 */
abstract class Account
{
    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class Player extends Account
{
    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class Coach extends Account
{
    // ...
}
```

This should create 3 tables `Account`, `Player` and `Coach`, though `Account` alone cannot be persisted, rather it will have a discriminator column + ID to link to. So, e.g. 'coach' '3' will join to Coach object with id 3.

**First Answer:**
If I understood you correctly and the password doesn't need to be provided directly, you can add to the `$password` annotation

```
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
```

Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: No, what I'm trying to do is saving the account table with username and password, but player and all subclasses with just the username foreign key to the account in order to be able to petform a join later.

Comment: The reason why I nedd to save both the Account Class and the subclasses is because later I will need to let them exchange some messages and I have tought to make a message entity with sender and receiver fields wich are 2 foreign keys to the username in the account table.